# string.Equals is not working as I expected in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following nc_resultsName values being returned from my dataset "NC-1" , "NC-2" , "C"

My aspx page looks like this

```
Text='<%# isCommentNC(Eval("nc_resultName").ToString()) %>'
```

and my cs page contains this method

```
    public Func<string, bool> isCommentNC = x => x.Equals("NC-1") || x.Equals("NC-2");
```

but my method only behaves correctly if I use Contains instead... Why?

```
    public Func<string, bool> isCommentNC = x => x.Contains("NC-1") || x.Contains("NC-2");
```

***EDIT**

Sorry Mistyped changed "C" to "NC-1" , same issue though

Comment: What's not working? Note that the first case doesn't account for "NC-1" at all.

Comment: @Yuck Sure it does. "NC-1" definitely `.Contains("C")`. I didn't say it was the way he *wanted*, just noting that "NC-1" isn't captured *at all* in case 1 (which probably explains why it's "not working")

Comment: Ha! Nice catch of faulty logic.

Comment: I suggest that you set aside ASP.NET, and build a small console application that demonstrates the problem, using the `Func`s you've got above. That'll help you see where the problem is (my guess? your data is not what you expect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your data doesn't contain any blanks before or after? Try Trimming your string before calling Equals on it...

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following nc_resultsName values being returned from my dataset "NC-1" , "NC-2" , "C"

How are you determining that?  If you're looking in the debugger, it's possible that an embedded null character is playing tricks on you.  .NET strings can contain those characters, but the debugger stops displaying the string at that point, as if they are C-style strings.

Make sure the debugger isn't playing tricks on you.

Comment: I changed  ` public Func<string, bool> isCommentNC = x => x;`and the correct data is being returned